# docker-compose no actualiza la imagen

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Tengo una imagen con código que necesito actualizar muy a menudo.
Para poder ver los nuevos cambios tengo que borrar los contenedores y crear un nuevo docker-compose.

Hay otra forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes subir la versión de los contenedores y desplegarlos con la nueva versión así no tendrás que eliminar los contenedores para que tomen los cambios

Comment: por ejemplo imagen:dev001, imagen:dev002 etc?

Comment: Si pero es mejor practica manejar un versionamiento estándar, es decir 3 o 4 números separados por puntos. Ejemplo: imagen-dev:0.0.1,  imagen-dev:0.0.2 ...

Answer (score 0):

Estuve intentando muchas cosas por algunas semanas y la única que me ha funcionado definitivamente es la siguiente:

```
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate
```

De este modo se actualizan sólo las imágenes y archivos con cambios y no es necesario hacer el re-build

Answer (score 0):

Los contenedores se borran automáticamente cuando haces:

> docker-compose down

Tal vez te refieres a borrar las imágenes, para eso te recomendaría hacer el build de tus imágenes dentro del docker-compose.

Así:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  webapp:
    build: ./dir
```

O algo más avanzado como:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  webapp:
    build:
      context: ./dir
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-alternate
      args:
        buildno: 1
```

Puedes ver más detalles en: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build